# i want to submit two actions with one form and one submit button in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

In my app i want the user click on participate button to participate to an event and i want he will receive an email in the same time when he click !

The 2 function work well in the app but i can't make them in the same time when the user click on participate button !!

**I have two routes with two different controllers:**

```
Route::post('/participations/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\EventController@participate')->name('participate');
Route::post('/event/mails','App\Http\Controllers\EmailController@participate')->name('mails');
```

**This is my form :**

```
<form  action="{{route('mails')}}" action="{{route('participate', [$event->id])}}" method="POST">@csrf

      <div class="modal-body">
  
        <div class="form-goup">
          <label>Your name *</label>
          <input type="text" name="friend_name" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-goup">
          <label>Your email *</label>
          <input type="email" name="friend_email" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Participate</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I can't find a way to fix that ! any help ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: why don't use queue to perform this solution you're looking for??? sending mail, could take time and user experience could go down, so you implement queue job (or notification) and just add to the code end in the EventController "participate" method to send the email to the user

Comment: thanks helped me a lot to solve the issue